# Has a team qualified first and last on pace before?

Tags: formula-1

In the [Sprint Qualifying for the 2022 São Paulo Grand Prix](https://www.formula1.com/en/results.html/2022/races/1137/brazil/qualifying.html), Haas' Kevin Magnussen qualified in first place and his team mate, Mick Schumacher, qualified in 20th (last) place.

While, admittedly, the final qualifying session was rain-affected, both drivers earned their position on pace alone - i.e. there were no mechanical issues or penalties applied.

Has this ever happened before, where a team qualifies both in first place and last place on actual driver lap times?

---

For clarification: I'm not including qualifying position as determined by a Sprint Race, but rather the classic qualifying format(s) - and Sprint Qualifying (as in this case) can be included.

Comment: Not quite the same thing, but the 1981 Monaco GP deserves an honourable mention. Nelson Piquet qualified on pole for Brabham, while team-mate Hector Rebaque failed to qualify at all - he was 23rd (out of 26), and only the top 20 got to start the race.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Apparently not.**

This was discussed during Sky Sports' coverage of the sprint race. Ted Kravitz asked David Croft whether a team had ever qualified first and last before, and Croft listed two examples: the 2017 Brazilian Grand Prix, and the 2018 Monaco Grand Prix. In the former, Valtteri Bottas took pole, while Lewis Hamilton crashed in Q1 and never set a lap time; in the latter, Daniel Ricciardo took pole, while Max Verstappen crashed in FP3 and his car wasn't repaired in time for Q1.

It's hard to prove a negative, and it wasn't stated whether those were the *only* examples, so this is a tentative "no", but nonetheless, my answer is **no, this doesn't appear to have ever happened before**.